# Flask REST API fake POST request

Tags: python, rest, flask, post

During unit tests of REST Flask server I've encountered following problem:
I have a view function that should handle POST request with collection of numbers
( Sample without function body )

```
@api.route("/last_op/add", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def post_add_last_operation():
    return request.data
```

For testing purposes I use **Flask.test_client()** object.

When trying to send POST request in following way:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
client = app.test_client()
client.post("/last_op/add", data={"collection": "1,2,3,4"})
```

I am receiving empty return value.
What am I missing?
Thanks in advance

Comment: does returning jsonify of your data make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `request.get_data()` instead.

If that still doesn't work, you can try passing your payload as JSON

```py
client.post('/last_op/add', json={'collection': '1,2,3,4'})
```

then in the handler use

```py
make_response(jsonify(request.get_json()))
```

to build your response.